# How to Save PDF to Laravel's Public Directory

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

When I execute my "make" method with the output below, it creates the file "0000.pdf" inside the "filesPDF" directory of the "Controllers" directory.

I would like it to be created within Laravel's "public" directory.

```
$pdf->make($pdf::OUTPUT_SAVE, __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'filesPDF' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '0000.pdf');
```

Comment: Try using the `public_path()` helper

Comment: it didn't work, unfortunately.